# Is the complete graph $K_n$ $n-1$-connected?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, extremal-graph-theory

Is the complete graph $K_n$ $n-1$-connected?

I'm trying to have a better understanding of k-connectedness and it helps to look at an extreme case. My intuition is that it's either that or it's 1-connected.

Comment: What is the def of k-connected?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/k-ConnectedGraph.html

Comment: Keep in mind a graph can be $k$-connected for many different values of $k$. You probably want to think about the connectivity, which is the maximum $k$ for which a graph is $k$ connected.

Comment: Note: If a graph is $k$-connected, then it is also $\ell$-connected for any $\ell<k$, because when removing $k$ vertices does not destroy the connectedness, neither does removing $\ell<k$ vertices.

Comment: @M.Winter you mean removing k-1 vertices does not destroy connectivity (i.e. a cycle is 2-connected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we remove $n-2$ vertices from $K_n$ we are left with $2$ connected (all possible edges were present in $K_n$, so this one still is) vertices, which is connected. So by definition $K_n$ is $n-1$ connected; in fact it's the only graph on $n$ vertices that is: if some $(v,w)$, with $v \neq w, v,w \in V$ is not in the edge set $E$ of a graph $G = (V,E)$ we can remove all $n-2$ points $V\setminus\{v,w\}$ from $G$ and then we'd be left with a disconnected $2$-vertex graph. So a graph $(V,E)$ is $(|V|-1)$-connected iff all possible edges are in $E$ already.